# How do these 9 LePage Super Glues differ?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Home Improvement Stack Exchange post: [How do these 9 LePage Super Glues differ?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/222511/how-do-these-9-lepage-super-glues-differ)

Why was this closed? It's blindingly obvious that this doesn't duplicate [How do these 5 Gorilla Super Glue differ?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/222499/how-do-these-5-gorilla-super-glue-differ), because the number of products in question differ and these brands differ!

[Solar Mike](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/222511/how-do-these-9-lepage-super-glues-differ#comment418866_222511) commented

> Have you read the instructions for each product? RTFM is usually a good start (Read The F.... Manual)

Yes, I did. But the instructions don't compare and contrast ALL NINE products.

Answer (score 1):

Several reasons I can think of based on [what is on topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

- The site is for home improvement, and your glasses are not your home. This would be more related to a hobby project.
- The cost of a job or product, since they will likely not be useful for future visitors.
- "Shopping assistance, product recommendations, or brand specific advice." This pretty much covers all three.

The closest this could get to being on topic would be "Which tools, materials, and best practices for home improvement task." However, for that to apply, we as that the questions be general enough to not be product specific and not be a product recommendations. In other words, the tool is a type of super glue, not a specific manufacturer's type of glue available from your local store.

For consistency, you're correct that one should not be left open while the other is closed. Unfortunately that means the question about 5 glues needs to be closed too.

Please see the other sections of the help center and take the [tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) for a better idea of how to participate here.